# change configurations of laravel on run time from database

Tags: php, laravel, security, laravel-5

i want to change the configurations at run time.
 I want to create a installer and configuration page for admin in which admin can enter the configuration Like Paypal's clients and secret keys, Stripe keys, Database connection and other API keys. Right now i m using .env file to manage the all the configurations is there a nice to way to achieve it.?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set config data at runtime for current request, you can use `config()` global helper:

```
config(['config.key' => 'value'])
```

If you want to overwrite some config data and keep it for following requests, you need to use [package](https://packagist.org/packages/nwidart/laravel-config-writer) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a file placed on the system (for example):

Routes:

```
if(File::exists(storage_path('/installed'))) {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return 'installer...';
    });
} else {
    //all your routes
}
```

Here you can paste all your routes that will handle the setup, after that you can make the file at the `storage_path('/installed')` and it will show your normal routes.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

You may use Laravel Config::set method to override config value for current request.

```
// app/config/project.php 
Config::set('project.secret_key', '123xxxxx');

app/config/mail.php 
Config::set('mail.username', 'new Username);
```